# @SendTo Annotation fails silently for ActiveMQ

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic

I am trying to push a JMS message to a standalone ActiveMQ broker in a SpringBoot Application using @SendTo annotiation, however the execution completes without error/exception but the message is not queued. Instead if I use JmsTemplate (commented in code), the message is queued. Is there any additional configuration required for using @SendTo. What am I doing wrong here?

**application.properties**

```
spring.activemq.broker-url= tcp://localhost:61616
spring.activemq.user= admin
spring.activemq.password= admin
spring.activemq.pool.enabled= false
```

**Spring Boot Application**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyCustomRouterApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(MyCustomRouterApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Service Method**

```
@Service
public class NotificationServiceImpl implements NotificationService {

    //@Autowired
    //JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Override
    @SendTo("inboundSyncQueue")
    public Map<String, Object> enqueueExchangeNotification(ExchangeNotification notification, String tenantId) throws RuntimeException {

        Map<String, Object> jmsMessage = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        jmsMessage.put("tenantId", tenantId);
        jmsMessage.put("source", ExternalNotificationSource.EXCHANGE);
        jmsMessage.put("payload", notification);
        //jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("inboundSyncQueue", notification);
        return jmsMessage;
    }

}
```

**maven pom**

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
      <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <!-- Required for ActiveMQ JMS Consumer -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
      <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <!-- Required for Guava In-memory Cache -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>21.0</version>
   </dependency>
   <!-- Required for String Utilities -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.7</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of @sendTo , I used jmsTemplate at producer.  Below is a method.
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(destinationQueue, message);

Note: It's a workaround.

Comment: that is what i ended up doing. The intent to use the annotation is to avoid the boilerplate coding for jmsTemplate and let spring manage it