# What is the difference beetween JmsTemplate and @SendTo()?

Tags: java, spring-jms

I have two application, one is sending request, another is answering, i'm trying to implement it using `@JmsListener`.

This code works:

```
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate (ConnectionFactory connectionFactory){
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        Destination destination = new ActiveMQQueue("replydestination");
        jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestination(destination);
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "somedestination",
            containerFactory = "defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory")
    public void receiveMessage (Message message) throws JMSException {
        jmsTemplate.send(new ActiveMQTextMessage());
    }
```

But when change to `@SendTo("replydestination")` it stops working:

```
    @JmsListener(destination = "somedestination",
            containerFactory = "defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory")
    @SendTo("replydestination")
    public Message receiveMessage (Message message) throws JMSException {
        return new ActiveMQTextMessage();
    }
```

Help me to understand why, and can i make this integration without using `JmsTemplate`.

Comment: Do you see any errors? There was a similar issue reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50579831/sendto-annotation-fails-silently-for-activemq).

Answer (score 1):

JMS messages should be constructed with methods from `javax.jms.Session` or with a builder like this:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "somedestination",
        containerFactory = "defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory")
@SendTo("replydestination")
public org.springframework.messaging.Message<String> listen(javax.jms.Message message) {
    org.springframework.messaging.Message<String> reply = MessageBuilder
            .withPayload("MyReply")
            .build();
    return reply;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works too...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So65570932Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So65570932Application.class, args);
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "foo")
    @SendTo("bar")
    String listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
        return in.toUpperCase();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(JmsTemplate template) {
        return args -> {
            template.convertAndSend("foo", "baz");
            template.setReceiveTimeout(10_000);
            System.out.println(template.receiveAndConvert("bar"));
        };
    }

}
```